# Confused with weird cascade issue

Tags: css, css-cascade

I'm having some kind of weird problem with my CSS. I refactored some code from @chriscoyier using the SMACSS approach to modularize it.

If I move .ribbon.green to the bottom of the CSS, it doesn't get applied. Is this something to do with the ribbon:after & ribbon:before ?

Moving it down to the botton seems to work fine in jsFiddle but not in Firefox or Chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/SkinnyGeek1010/cDWKe/1/

Any ideas of why it does this? and is there anyway to move .ribbon.green down to the bottom? This would make it easier to change the "skin" with a mixin.

** added dropbox html ** 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1407764/www/stackoverflow/corner-ribbon/green_ribbon_example.html

Comment: "seems to work fine in jsFiddle but not in Firefox or Chrome" That's nonsense. jsFiddle isn't a browser!

Comment: You jsfiddle code, when used to construct a standalone document, looks the same as in jsfiddle. So the problem is probably elsewhere in your real page. Consider posting its URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it. It is working fine even if you moved .ribbon.green to bottom. May be conflicting with some other rules.

Comment: Hmmmm really weird... the html doc just has body and html tags, nothing more. At any rate when I just tried it moving with textmate (again) it works perfectly fine.

Comment: sometimes it happens like this.. cheers :)